# numpy variance vs homegrown variance (different result)

Tags: python, numpy

I am reading calculating variance and see a formula `variance = sum( (vals - mean(vals))**2 )` implemented in Python like:

```
def variance(values, mean):
    return sum([(x-mean)**2 for x in values])
```

I used this implementation and also walked through it step by step in a notebook and got the same answer.  However, when I used `<np.array>.var()`, I got a different result.  Is the numpy implementation different?  Is the function stated earlier incorrect?

With a randomly generated 4-element array `nums` like:

```
array([[0.10193815],
       [0.99458125],
       [0.57937386],
       [0.27331835]])
```

`nums.var()` = `0.11502594279263058`

`variance(nums, nums.mean())` = `0.4601037711705223`

Comment: That is not the variance, the variance is the *average* of the sum of squared differences from the mean, you are simply taking the sum of squared differences

Comment: From https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.var.html : The variance is the average of the squared deviations from the mean, i.e., var = `mean(abs(x - x.mean())**2)`.

Comment: Thanks all.  Looks like the blog I read had the wrong implementation.

Comment: There is a difference between _variance_ and _sample variance_.  _Variance_ is based on the whole population (or a probability distribution), and _sample variance_ is an estimate of this variance based on a random sample of this population or distribution.  However, if `values` is a random sample, then calculating the sample variance by the mean of `(value - m)**2`, where `m` is the sample mean, will be a _biased_ estimator.  See also: https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/100041.

Answer (score 4):

There is well-known problem with NumPy std deviation (and variance) - there is no [Bessel correction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bessel%27s_correction).

E.g. Python 3.8, Win10 x64

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

a = np.asarray([1., 2., 3., 4., 5.])

print(np.std(a))
print(pd.Series(a).std())
```

will print

```
1.4142135623730951
1.5811388300841898
```

You have to do correction manually.

```
print(np.std(a)*np.sqrt((l := len(a))/(l-1.0)))
```

will print

```
1.5811388300841898
```

in full agreement with Pandas and pretty much all other software. For example, in **R**

```
x <- c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5)
sd(x)
```

will print

```
[1] 1.581139
```

UPDATE

IT is worth mentioning that NumPy now provides additional parameter to fix for bessel correction (and compute unbiased estimator) - ddof. Default is 0, but when you set it to 1, right result will be printed

```
print(np.std([1., 2., 3., 4., 5.], ddof=1))
```

prints

```
1.5811388300841898
```

Comment: I would hesitate to call that a problem.  It's the difference between a sample and population statistic

Comment: @anon01 Maybe, but still different from pretty much anything else. You just have to remember it

Comment: While interesting, this seems not to be the issue in this question.

Comment: @mkrieger1, Well, original problem was corrected in the comments, but there might be another source of difference I pointed out - if you manually implement formula for variance/stddev WITH Bessel correction (again, as written in many places), you still would be different from NumPy implementation

Comment: @mkrieger1 What I'm saying, your answer is incorrect, in my humble opinion - you have to divide by 3, not by 4. As soon as you divide by 3, you will be in-line with Bessel-corrected NumPy as well as any other statistical package there. I provided example in **R**, you could check S, Stata etc

Answer (score 1):

https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.var.html says:

> The variance is the average of the squared deviations from the mean, i.e., `var = mean(abs(x - x.mean())**2)`.

i.e., where you are using `sum`, NumPy uses `mean`.

If you divide your result by 4 (the length of `nums`) you should get the same value.

Comment: Interesting, so either the blog post I read was wrong or numpy is.  I'll go with the blog post :)

Comment: This would be wrong result, there is no Bessel correction in the numpy stddev/variance. You have to divide by 3, not by 4.

Comment: @SamDillard I can't tell if you're joking or not

Comment: @anon01 You can't...?